# Extracting information from a third-party Python module?

Tags: python

NOTE:  I've worked in Java for years but I'm new to Python, so I apologize if this is a kind of vague question.   I'm just thrashing around trying to make something work.

I'm trying to use a third-party Python module which is an application SDK.   The Python module is a wrapper for an underlying legacy C SDK.

The documentation for this module is brutally bad - it's basically a list of included classes and methods, with little-to-no explanation of what the methods do or how they relate to the underlying C function calls.  (For example, in one case the Python method takes five arguments, the underlying C function takes six.   No indication what the difference is, or what the arguments should be.   This is typical.)

Is there any way I can look into this compiled Python module (source code is NOT provided) and gather more information?

Comment: If the C function uses an opaque data type as the first argument, Python usually replaces this with the class itself.

Comment: What's the module?

Comment: @Aya - it's the Lightwave 3D lwsdk module.   You can read the docs here if you're interested:  http://static.lightwave3d.com/sdk/2015/python/index.html

Comment: Looks like it's embedded into the binary. What do you get if you do `import lwsdk` then `print lwdsk`?

Comment: `<module 'lwsdk' from 'C:\Program Files\NewTek\LightWave_2015.3\bin\lwsdk\__init__.py'>` .   Not much help :(

Comment: It might be. It suggests the source code for the Python wrapper is in `C:\Program Files\NewTek\LightWave_2015.3\bin\lwsdk`.

Comment: Ah, there is some good stuff in there.   I'll check it out.   Thank you!   If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good starting point for finding information about a module is to do...

```
>>> import <modulename>
>>> <modulename>
```

It's usually one of four possible types...

---

**1. Built-in**

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys
module 'sys' (built-in)>
```

These are typically written in C, and compiled into the Python interpreter binary.

---

**2. Dynamically-loaded library**

```
>>> import parser
>>> parser
<module 'parser' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/parser.x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

These are also typically written in C, but are stored in separate binary files. Common file extensions include: `.pyd`, `.dll`, and `.so`.

---

**3. Python module**

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket
<module 'socket' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.pyc'>
```

These are at least partly written in Python, and the source code can usually be viewed by removing the `c` from the end of the filename, i.e. `/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py`.

It's also quite common for modules which are written in Python to import other binary modules, to do things which can't be done in pure Python. For example...

```
>>> socket._socket
<module '_socket' (built-in)>
```

---

**4. Python package**

```
>>> import xml
>>> xml
<module 'xml' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc'>
```

These are also at least partly written in Python, but often the file `__init__.py` is empty, and the source code is contained in other files in the same directory, i.e. `/usr/lib/python2.7/xml`.